# document.removeEventListener javascript

Tags: javascript, events

How can I remove this type of listener?

```
document.addEventListener("onSomething", function(){
  //Do something
});
```

when try to remove return number argument exception, way a function in second parameter but i not have a function.

```
 document.removeEventListener("customUploadComplete")
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to make a reference to the function in order to remove it. So pull it out into a function so you can remove it.

```
var thisThing = function(){
  //Do something
}

document.addEventListener("onSomething", thisThing);
document.removeEventListener("onSomething", thisThing);
```

Comment: Arrived too late :-) @JG73 This is exactly what you need to do btw !

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a function in order to remove it. This is because you need to reference it upon removal so that the browser can recognize which event to remove.

This will not work:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("clicked") });
btn.removeEventListener("click", function() { alert("clicked") });
```

because there is no reference to the function. Each function is unique, even if they have the same code within them.

If you declare a function you can store a reference to that function, and then remove it:

```
function clickEvent() {
  alert("clicked!");
}
btn.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
btn.removeEventListener("click", clickEvent);
```

Here's an example:

```js
let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document),
  btn = $("#b1"),
  add = $("#b2"),
  remove = $("#b3");

function clickEvent() {
  alert("click");
}

btn.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);

remove.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.removeEventListener("click", clickEvent);
   alert("event removed!");
});

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
  alert("event added!");
});
```

```html
<button id="b1">click me</button>
<p/>
<button id="b2">Add Event Listener</button> <button id="b3">Remove Event Listener</button>
```