# removeEventListener doesn't work, and no error's are returned

Tags: javascript, event-listener, removeeventlistener

As you can see in the code below I'm trying to remove an mouse move event listener however this listener doesn't get removed, and no errors are returned, as you can see the first time you double click on the menu the listener gets added, this works fine. the second time you double click it should get removed..
but it does not. I'm I removing it the wrong way ? can someone please help me with this problem I would really appreciate it..

```
function DragMenus()
{
    ClickedSoManyTimes = 0;
    Menu = document.getElementsByClassName("Box1");
    AllMns = [Menu[1], Menu[2], Menu[3], Menu[4]];

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < AllMns.length; i++)
    {
        AllMns[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function(i)
        {
            function MouseMove()
            {
                 // Do Something
            };

            ClickedSoManyTimes = ClickedSoManyTimes + 1;
    
            if(Number.isInteger(ClickedSoManyTimes/2))                 
            {
               console.log("Stop");
               // delete Listener
               document.removeEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove); // Fails
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Start");
                document.addEventListener("mousemove", MouseMove);
            };
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: ClickedSoManyTimes is something that common to all the menus. You will have to maintain a variable that holds the state for each menu

Comment: Please show us some markup. Also, what do you mean by "AllMns are menu's" ? Where do you define `AllMns`?

Comment: You are recreating `MouseMove` every time your `dblclick` listener fires. That will not match the original function you passed to `addEventListener` therefore it won't be removed as you are not passing the original function

Comment: Minor point as it doesn't affect this particular problem, but it looks as though you are trying to pass i as an index to the event handler, it will actually be the event object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409218/7840347), the event listener can only be removed by using a reference to the *original* function that you referenced when you created it. In your code, multiple event listeners are created on the document, and each gets its own function `MouseMove`. When you then double-click another one of the items, it tries to remove an event listener related to *its* copy of `MouseMove`, but that may not be the copy that was originally used.

The best remedy is to take the definition of `MouseMove` out of your double-click-eventhandler, so it is *one* function instead of many that have the same name but are not the same function.