# react function not using updated state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

My handleKeyUp function is not using any of the new values in the state. In the function, playingTrackInd is always equal to -1, even when the state has been updated for playingTrackInd to be something else.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

export interface Track {
    artist: string,
    title: string,
    uri: string,
    albumUrl: string,
    previewUrl?: string,
}

export default function Dashboard() {
    const [playingTrackInd, setPlayingTrackInd] = useState<number>(-1);
    const tracks = useRef<Array<Track>>([]);
   
    // add keylistener
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

    }, []);

    // this function always has playingTrackInd as -1, even when the state has been updated by setPlayingTrackInd
    function handleKeyUp(e: any) {
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            // right arrow pressed
            if (playingTrackInd === tracks.current.length - 1) {
                getRandomTrack(() => setPlayingTrackInd(prevInd => prevInd + 1));
            }
            else {
                setPlayingTrackInd(prevInd => prevInd + 1)
            }

        }
        else if (e.keyCode === 37) { // left arrrow key pressed
            if (playingTrackInd > 0) {
                setPlayingTrackInd(prevInd => prevInd - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // function that gets random track and adds it to tracks
    function getRandomTrack(callback?: Function) {
        getRandomTrackFromApi().then((track) => {
            tracks.current.push(track);
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        })
    }

    // get first random track and set playingTrackInd to 0. This happens as soon as the component is loaded
    useEffect(() => {
        if (playingTrackInd === -1) { 
            getRandomTrack(() => setPlayingTrackInd(0));
        }
        getRandomTrack();
        getRandomTrack();


        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return (
        (component that depends on tracks[playingTrackInd])
    );
}
```

I can't understand why playingTrackInd is always -1 only in the handleKeyUp function. Everywhere else, including the return statement, it is the proper value. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the effect below:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
    }, []);
```

As you can see, you're registering `handleKeyUp` once (Effect is triggered once, on mount, because deps array is empty). `handleKeyUp` remembers last value of `playingTrackInd` via Closure (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). When `playingTrackInd` is updated, component rerenders, new `handleKeyUp` function is created, but you've already registered your `handleKeyUp` that remembers old value, and you're not updating that listener.

You can fix that issue by for example by passing `handleKeyUp` to dependency array like below:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
        }
    }, [handleKeyUp]);
```

Don't forget to remove listener before new listener is going to be registered. Solution is not ideal, because `handleKeyUp` function is created every render. Same issue exists in your second `useEffect` hook.

I strongly recommend to wrap your functions into `useCallback` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and pass all dependencies in deps arrays. That way your fuctions won't be created every render, but only when their dependencies change.

Another thing is that there's an eslint rule that will help you track all required deps in deps arrays, check `exhaustive-deps` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. What would the 'id' variable you pass in removeEventListener be?

Comment: @Arj I've updated my comment, you can pass same handler you've passed to addEventListener. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409015/document-removeeventlistener-javascript