# State in React function never updates (even asynchronously, and with a good dependency array)

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm sure this is a simple React rule, but I'm really struggling to find an answer to this problem because many people make similar mistakes that don't seem to apply to me ([async misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900377/why-is-react-setstate-hook-not-updating-immediately), direct variable mutation, [wrong dependency array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438920/react-function-not-using-updated-state), etc.) Let me explain.

I want to setup a heartbeat type system where players send messages back and forth every 3 seconds to all competitors to say "I'm alive and still connected." using WebRTC. The connection is fine, and sending/receiving messages works fine. Any player can send data about themselves, a heartbeat, or a few other things, but only one type of data at a time.

I have a function/useCallback (I tried both) called `ProcessMessage` that reads these incoming messages. If the message contains data on a competitor, it gets set with `setCompetitors`. If the data contains a heartbeat, it sends back an acknowledgement (or, it should). Heartbeats do arrive correctly.

In `ProcessMessage`, the state `competitors` is always the initial value of just []. However, in other places, `competitors` updates just fine. When I use a breakpoint at the place heartbeats are being read, the `competitors` state is correct. The only thing I can think of is that the `ProcessMessage` function reads/sets incoming competitor data and also reads incoming heartbeats. **It never does both at the same time**, though. Competitor data come in, then a few seconds later, another message with a heart beat comes in, so I don't know why this would cause `competitors` to always be the initial value. I have `competitors` in my dependency array at the end of `ProcessMessage` when I write it as a callback hook.

Just to be clear, this is NOT a case of:

```
/* Not this kind of problem, I'm pretty sure. I know setCompetitors is async */
setCompetitors(competitorData);
console.log(competitors);
```

I've cut out as much code as I can while still hopefully leaving enough to make sense of what's happening.

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Peer from 'peerjs';

function App() {
  const [myData,      setMyData]      = useState({/* default data, updates fine */});
  const [competitors, setCompetitors] = useState([]);

  /* Create WebRTC connection useEffect here, works fine */

  // Heartbeats to all competitors - sends correctly
  useEffect(() => {
    const heartbeats = [];
    competitors.forEach(competitor => {  // competitors is fine here
      heartbeats.push(setInterval(() => {
        competitor.conn.send({heartbeat : {
          stage: 1,
          playerKey: myData.playerKey
        }});
        console.log("Heartbeat stage 1 sent");  // gets sent correctly
      }, 3000));
    });
    return () => {
      heartbeats.forEach(heartbeat => { clearInterval(heartbeat); });
    }
  }, [competitors]);

  const ProcessMessage = useCallback((data) => {

    /* If the data has competitor data, it won't have a heartbeat too */

    /* check if data contains competitor data */
    const newCompetitor = data.competitor;
    if(newCompetitor) {
      console.log("New competitor data received");
      setCompetitors(oldCompetitors => {
        let newCompetitors = [...oldCompetitors];
        /* Some newCompetitor integration logic, partial updates, error checking, etc */
        return newCompetitors;
      });
    }


    /* Code to deal with other types of data here - works fine */


    /* check if data contains a heartbeat */
    const heartbeat = data.heartbeat;
    if(heartbeat) {

      /* This is the problem. competitors is always just [] */
      const competitor = competitors.find(comp => comp.playerKey === heartbeat.playerKey);
      if(competitor) {
        /* Code to deal with incoming heartbeat - never fires*/
      } else {
        console.log("Heartbeat could not be returned");  // This always fires
      }
    }
  }, [boardData, competitors]);

  /* Lots more logic, functions, etc */
  /* Beautiful return statement */
```

If any additional code could help clarify what's going on, please ask and I'll update the question. Thanks all.

btw, full code can be seen here: [GitHub](https://github.com/cdehaan/wrapfield/blob/master/src/App.js)
The offending line is 149

Comment: Well-asked question. Do you see the output: "New competitor data received"? If so, how many times?

Comment: Is there a way that you can check each step in the "Some newCompetitor integration logic, partial updates, error checking, etc " is actually working ? It may be bombing and giving you an empty array

Comment: @Nathan Thank you.
I do see "New competitor data received" output once on the host of the game.
(The person joining has a similar log message when they send their data, and it fires once at the right time.)

Comment: @RyanZeelie That's a good point.
When I set a breakpoint at the final line, ```return newCompetitors;``` it is setting ```competitors``` to what I expect.
Also, after that, I can see in developer tools that the data has been stored in the ```competitors``` state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in this line:

`let newCompetitors = [...oldCompetitors];`

You're just copying the old state, which is empty.

If should be

`let newCompetitors = [...oldCompetitors, newCompetitor];`

That way you actually add the new competitor to the state.

Comment: My syntax on adding to an array after spreading is rusty, so it might not work as is, but you get the idea.

Comment: He's copying the old state and then making changes to newCompetitors before returning it. I think it's safe to assume that it's getting added during the additional logic

Comment: Yes, I glossed over this a bit, but there's quite a bit of logic between ```let newCompetitors = [...oldCompetitors];``` and ```return newCompetitors;``` which takes data from ```newCompetitor``` and incorporates it into ```newCompetitors```. I check by putting a breakpoint at the return line, and indeed ```newCompetitors``` has been correctly updated.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Hmm. So the ProcessMessage callback is called multiple times-- and it handles two different types of events. We know that added a competitor works, because you added a breakpoint and see the state being set. Perhaps during the second flow, heartbeat, you're accidentally clobbering the state and resetting it to [] before you reach the heartbeat handling logic? Can you check that the state is set to a non-empty array before AND after you attempt to process the heartbeat?

Comment: It's definitely a strange issue. If this doesn't work, my gut is saying it has something to do with the useCallback usage and changing state that is in the dependency array-- though that should still work, and you said you've tried it w/o useCallback

Comment: @Nathan Yes, that's a possible reason, but I put a breakpoint on the first line of ```ProcessMessage``` once heartbeats started being passed and even then, ```competitors``` was still ```[]```.
Annoyingly, while holding on that breakpoint, I can see the data showing up in the hook correctly over in the "Components" tab in developers tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workable solution. Even though I don't know why my original code failed, my workaround isn't too messy, so in case I can help anyone else, I'll outline what I did.

First, I made a new state (which could maybe be better thought of as "current heartbeat" actually) as follows:

```
const [heartbeats,  setHeartbeats]  = useState(null)
```

Then, I changed the heartbeat processing part of `ProcessMessage` to the following:

```
    if(heartbeat) {
        if(heartbeat.stage === 1) {
          setHeartbeats(heartbeat);
        }
  
        if (heartbeat.stage === 2) {
          console.log("Heartbeat stage 2 received:");  // This fires correctly
          console.log(heartbeat); // Looks good
          /* Code to mark this player as "Active" to go here */
        }  
    }
```

Finally, I added a `useEffect` that picks up on the change to `heartbeats` as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!heartbeats) { return; }
    const competitor = competitors.find(comp => comp.playerKey === heartbeats.playerKey);
    if(competitor) {
      competitor.conn.send({heartbeat : {
        stage: 2,
        playerKey: myData.playerKey
      }});
      console.log("Heartbeat stage 2 sent:"); // This fires now
    } else {
      console.log("Heartbeat could not be returned");
    }
  }, [heartbeats, competitors]);  // Works even if competitors is removed
```

In this function, competitors is available as expected. That means heartbeats are returned (as stage 2), and my `ProcessMessage` picks them up as a returned heartbeat.

However, this code seems more fragile, not to mention more complex than it should be. I'm worried setting many heartbeats might result in skipped beats. Also, I've added a state hook that seems unnecessary.